# Keeping track of songs in playlists

Tags: itunes, search

Is there a way to track what songs in an iTunes account appear in playlists? i.e. -- some songs may appear in 2 playlists, some appear in none. How can I know that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your iTunes Music Library, right-click on a song's title and select `Show in Playlist` from the menu. A submenu will pop out, showing all of the playlists to which the song belongs.

[image]